# Python integration in Vim on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, vimscript-python, installing, linux-debian

I am relatively new to programming, and I built a mobile computer with a Pi at its heart to learn on the go. Ideally, I would use Vim as my IDE for Python 3. However, every attempt at installation results in Python not being recognized by Vim (via `vim --version`).

My best guess is that I need to compile VIM by hand. I have no idea how to do so, and I haven't found anything online that can help.

My OS is the Raspbian version of Debian.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Please explain like I'm 5.

**TLDR:** Vim will not recognize Python 3, and I do not know why.

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome` work? Posting as a comment since it's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a terminal version of vim which supports python (alongs with Lua, Perl, Ruby, and Tcl) without a GUI. I'd recommend to use the [vim-nox package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/vim-nox).

You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install vim-nox
```

If you are looking for a GUI version [vim-gnome](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vim-gnome) is what you are looking for.

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

---

**Foot page note**

Before using `apt-get install` you should call `apt-get update`, this will update the list of packages available. This is off topic for this site but [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-packages-in-ubuntu-and-debian-with-apt-get-apt-cache) has a simple tutorial to get started with `apt-get` commands and [ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) provides a list of the useful commands.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you.

I want the terminal version. I attempted:
sudo apt-get install vim-nox

I recieved multiple error messages due to certain IP addresses not being found. Do you have an alternative I could try?

Comment: Have you tried using `apt-get update ` before installing?